# WiX 3.8 integration with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2013, wix3.8

I am using Visual Studio 2013 for Winforms development. I recently installed Wix Tools version 3.8 for setup and installation projects. However, when I create a new setup project the WIx designer buttons do not show up on the Solution Explorer toolbar. I am a newbe to Wix. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "designer buttons"? Do you expect there to be a visual designer of the WiX dialogs? If so, you'll be disappointed - there's no such thing in pure WiX. You'll have to write XML code, or google for third-party stuff out there...

Comment: I have tried to look at every Wix tutorial I can find. For Wix 3.8 and VS 2013 there are buttons in the Solution Explorer that help with things like registry entries, etc.

Comment: That's probably not WiX. Please add a screenshot and link to the tutorial.

Comment: Tom, you are right. I was watching a demo on YouTube and thought it was a builtin feature of Wix. Turns out it was demo for a product by AddIn Express. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Install Designer for Visual Studio WiX Setup Projects, to work with normal setup project deployment like environment.
Just Install this:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/daee5804-806a-479b-8c20-5ba620264b93
to see View Editor in your setup projects.
**Note:** It is not open source...